# Reset index name in elasticsearch dsl

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm trying to create an ETL that extracts from mongo, process the data and loads into elastic. I will do a daily load so I thought of naming my index with the current date. This will help me for a later processing I need to do with this first index.
I used elasticsearch dsl guide: https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/persistence.html
The problem that I have comes from my little experience with working with classes. I don't know how to reset the Index name from the class.
Here is my code for the class (*custom_indices.py*):

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import Document, Date, Integer, Keyword, Text
from elasticsearch_dsl.connections import connections
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search
import datetime

class News(Document):
    title = Text(analyzer='standard', fields={'raw': Keyword()})
    manual_tagging = Keyword()

    class Index:
        name = 'processed_news_'+datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")

    def save(self, ** kwargs):
        return super(News, self).save(** kwargs)

    def is_published(self):
        return datetime.now() >= self.processed
```

And this is the part of the code where I create the instance to that class:

```
from custom_indices import News
import elasticsearch
import elasticsearch_dsl
from elasticsearch_dsl.connections import connections
import pandas as pd
import datetime

connections.create_connection(hosts=['localhost'])
News.init()
for index, doc in df.iterrows():
    new_insert = News(meta={'id': doc.url_hashed}, 
                      title = doc.title,
                      manual_tagging = doc.customTags,
                   )
    new_insert.save()
```

Every time I call the "News" class I would expect to have a new name. However, the name doesn't change even if I load the class again (*from custom_indices import News*). I know this is only a problem I have when testing but I'd like to know how to force that "reset". Actually, I originally wanted to change the name outside the class with this line right before the loop:

```
News.Index.name = "NEW_NAME"
```

However, that didn't work. I was still seeing the name defined on the class.
Could anyone please assist?
Many thanks!
PS: this must be just an object oriented programming issue. Apologies for my ignorance on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could take advantage of the fact that `Document.init()` [accepts an `index` keyword argument](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/blob/master/elasticsearch_dsl/document.py#L131). If you want the index name to get set automatically, you could implement `init()` in the `News` class and call `super().init(...)` in your implementation.

A simplified example (python 3.x):

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import Document
from elasticsearch_dsl.connections import connections
import datetime


class News(Document):
    @classmethod
    def init(cls, index=None, using=None):
        index_name = index or 'processed_news_' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")
        return super().init(index=index_name, using=using)
```

Comment: thanks jDo. But what should I do with the "name" inside the inner class Index. If I leave as it is or with a static name just for testing, when calling News.init() I still see that it creates the Index with the name indicates inside class Index
I tried calling the init funcion from index but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the index when you call **save()** .

```
new_insert.save('processed_news_' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Example as following.

```
# coding: utf-8

import datetime

from elasticsearch_dsl import Keyword, Text, \
    Index, Document, Date
from elasticsearch_dsl.connections import connections

HOST = "localhost:9200"

index_names = [
    "foo-log-",
    "bar-log-",
]

default_settings = {"number_of_shards": 4, "number_of_replicas": 1}

index_settings = {
    "foo-log-": {
        "number_of_shards": 40,
        "number_of_replicas": 1
    }
}


class LogDoc(Document):
    level = Keyword(ignore_above=256)

    date = Date(format="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")

    hostname = Text(fields={'fields': Keyword(ignore_above=256)})
 
    message = Text()

    createTime = Date(format="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")


def auto_create_index():
    '''自动创建ES索引'''
    connections.create_connection(hosts=[HOST])

    for day in range(3):
        dt = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=day)
        for index in index_names:
            name = index + dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            settings = index_settings.get(index, default_settings)

            idx = Index(name=name)
            idx.document(LogDoc)
            idx.settings(**settings)
            try:
                idx.create()
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                continue
            print("create index %s" % name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    auto_create_index()
```